# Can't get bind to redirect domain

Tags: networking, dns, bind

So, I decided to set up bind as a DNS server (to be totally honest, it was just a practical exercise since I'm studying for the Network+.) But I can't make it work.

I start with a zone in named.conf:

```
zone "example.com" {
type master;
file "example.txt";
};
```

And I have the following DNS file.  Bind is running on localhost, as is a python3 simple http server with the page I'm looking for.  The example.txt is:

```
; example.com
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns1.example.com. root.example.com. (
                     2006020201 ; Serial
                         604800 ; Refresh
                          86400 ; Retry
                        2419200 ; Expire
                         604800); Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      ns1
        IN      A       127.0.0.1
ns1     IN      A       127.0.0.1
mail    IN      A       127.0.0.1 ; We have our mail server somewhere else.
www     IN      A       127.0.0.1
client1 IN      A       127.0.0.1 ; We connect to client1 very often.
```

My understanding is that this should cause example.com to be reported as localhost, which will in fact resolve to my server.  However, I have no idea why NS1 is needed before the dot, and honestly it doesn't work.  At all.
(I figured - vaguely - that ns1 defines which nameserver ie DNS serer was to be used, and that of course also resides on Localhost.)

If someone could expose my inadequacy I'd be grateful.  This is just a learning experience - I learned what a network ID and such was four days ago, but I've been studying ~10 hours a day.

Comment: [SOA Resource Records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOA_Resource_Record) its the primary master for this zone.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually more then 1 thing going on here.

The "ns1" in the SOA record defines the authorative zone, ie which Nameserver has the original version of the data. In ost setups this is ignored entirely, but it might be useful for manually tracking down inconsistencies if authorative nameservers answer differently for the same zone. AFAIK this is not used as part of the DNS lookup process.

The issue you are most likely having is that the DNS server is not being queried, and the DNS server you are using does not know about your DNS configuration for your zone.  DNS servers look to their upstream or to the root nameservers to find the zone, and these are configured with your registrar outside your DNS software.

The exception is if you have the nameservers on your computer set to use your own DNS server. I expect that this is not the case here - unless you set your Nameserver manually on your PC.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean: I set my (windows) default DNS server to 127.0.0.1.  I start the bind ICS service.  When I do this, everything (sadly) works normally.  When I stop the bind service (and flush DNS) my computer can't find any web-pages, so I am assuming that I am using the BIND server.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you are missing the entry for the domain itself. Try adding in `example.com. IN A 127.0.0.1`. Don't forget the period.